# Alternative means of payment for Careers?

Tags: support, jobs, payment

Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying that I think stackoverflow llc won't handle my data securely, but, it's just that, well, I'm a developer too and I've seen where credit card data ends up.

Is there an alternative means of payment for careers?

Comment: It sucks not having a credit card...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also:

1. The credit card transmission is https://
2. We don't store your credit card information *anywhere* in our database, *ever*.

Comment: I'm glad. Once a *"friend"* of mine found in the recycle sheets a listing of credit card numbers. I knew ( I meant *"he"* knew ) that was not the right place to keep working

Comment: So, after your statement of not storing the cc information I'm ok to proceed.

Comment: I just payed for the filing, and would have definitely used paypal if the option was there, rather than having to type in my details all over again, just two clicks and it's paid. A bit like openid for payment I guess.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if you wish you pay for careers you can use also use paypal - however it's more of a manual process for us to activate your account, so please allow 24-48 hours after you send funds via paypal for activation.

The paypal address is:  careers@stackoverflow.com

Please be sure to include your email address that is present on your careers CV.

Comment: Great!, I think I personally trust more in Jeff than paypal :P

Answer (score 1):

Blame Fedex. They refused to take the last live goat I tried to send.

Comment: Maybe the payment was void because the goat was no longer live.

Comment: Yeah, and I was more thinking in a human heart as payment,  but then SO would have to give me change.